# I get a Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] error when I try to pass my middleware to my route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I created a middleware function and tried to pass it to my route but I get a Route.get() requires a callback function but got a [object Object] error. I am new to node.

This is my middleware function

```
const {User} = require('../models/user');
async function auth(req, res, next){
    let errors = [];
    if(!req.cookies['userAuth']) errors.push({text: 'Authentication failed'});
    try{
        const user = await User.findById(req.cookies['userAuth']);
        req.user = user._id;
        next();
        
    }catch(err){
        res.redirect('login')
    }
}

module.exports.auth = auth;
```

And here is the code for my route

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const nauth = require('../middleware/nAuth');
router.get('/dashboard', nauth, (req, res) => {
    res.render('dashboard')
});
```